# Types for jquery plugins

Tags: jquery, typescript, types

My IDE (PHPStorm) and Typescript complains that it doesn't know `modal`.
I'm adding modal to JQuery Interface with reference but it is still not working.
I have @types/jquery installed.

```
/// <reference types="jquery"/>
interface JQuery {
    modal(): JQuery;
    modal(any): any;
    modal(method: 'show'): any;
}

export class Auth {
    public constructor() {

    }

    public show() {
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    }
}
```

Comment: The `modal()` method comes from jQueryUI - so you may need to add a different reference for it to be recognised by your IDE

Comment: It's from bootstrap - I don't know if bootstrap and jquery-ui are the same...

Comment: Ah ok. Still, the issue is the same - you need to add a reference for Bootstrap. Note that jQuery, jQueryUI and Bootstrap are all separate libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `@types/jquery` installed one of the reasons might be that you are missing to specify it in your `tsconfig.json` like this:

```
{ 
     "compilerOptions": { 
         //your other options goes here
         "types": [
            "jquery",
            "bootstrap"
         ]
     }
}
```

Hope this helps.